# generating to generate numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to generate a set of an array using the code below.I will try to explain what I have done too

First:

```
example = np.zeros(8,dtype=int)
print(example)
```

which gave me output:
`[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`

then:

```
input=np.array([],int)
for i in range(0,8):
  if i <8:
    example[i-1]=0
    example[i]=1
    print(example)
  input = np.append(input,example)
print(input)
```

which then gave me:

```
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
```

and atlast i do this
`input = np.append(input,example)`
which gives me: `[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]`
but here's how I want this:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

or something like that. now, I tried to search, I get errors for whatever I try.hope I get as soon as possible.

Comment: You did not read the `np.append` docs (carefully enough)!  As documented it is flattening the inputs.  `np.append` is not a clone of the list append.  Don't try use it in the same way.  Better yet don't use it at all.  Too many pitfalls for the beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you're after the identity matrix.

```
    X = np.identity(8, dtype=int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape the array with `.reshape()` (don't use `input` as variable name, here `myInput` should be your `input` variable):

```
myInput = myInput.reshape(8,8)
```

Also you can shorten it using `np.identity`:

```
myInput = np.identity(8, dtype=int)
```

Answer (score 0):

To finish your attempt, you should write `input = np.append(input,example).reshape(8,8)`.
Alternatively, you can directly generate the desired output using `out = np.diag(np.ones(8))`

Comment: I tried to use reshape but I got this ` ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 8 into shape (8,8)`.some other answer worked for me, so thanks u